# Why this comparision fails?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Any idea why this happens? `a` is a BigDecimal.

```
a                               # => 87.6
(word_count * b).to_f           # => 87.6
a.to_f == (word_count * b).to_f # => false
```

Comment: I'd be very wary of comparing floating-point numbers by equality. The nature of floating point numbers makes them imprecise, so two numbers that ought to be equal may vary by a very small amount. Try something like `(a.to_f - (word_count * b).to_f).abs < 0.01`

Comment: Pls see http://www.lahey.com/float.htm (and many similar articles)

Comment: try seeing what 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001 shows up in your console as, and you'll get a better idea of what's going on.  If you just want to compare what you see, then calling `to_s` instead of `to_f` might work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain to you why this could happen, that is the original question.

The first thing to understand here is that what appears as return on the `irb` is the cast to a string. So, for example:

```
class A
  def to_s
    "return value"
  end
end
A.new
=> return value
```

Also, the `.to_s` method is not related to the comparison method. They had two different implementations.

So you can have something like this:

```
class A
  def to_s
    "87.6"
  end
end

class B
  def to_s
    "87.6"
  end
end

A.new
=> 87.6
B.new
=> 87.6
A.new == B.new
=> false
```

Float point numbers are really hard to compare. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

> Comparison of floating-point numbers, as defined by the IEEE standard, is a bit different from usual integer comparison. Negative and positive zero compare equal, and every NaN compares unequal to every value, including itself. All values except NaN are strictly smaller than +∞ and strictly greater than −∞. Finite floating-point numbers are ordered in the same way as their values (in the set of real numbers).
>
> To a rough approximation, the bit representation of an IEEE binary floating-point number is proportional to its base 2 logarithm, with an average error of about 3%. (This is because the exponent field is in the more significant part of the datum.) This can be exploited in some applications, such as volume ramping in digital sound processing.

So, as a personal opinion, the best thing is never compare equality of floating point numbers. This will avoid some caveats in the future, even if you logic is correct right now. I suggest truncate or round it before compare.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found to make it work as I want is:

```
a.to_s.to_f
```

Casting `.to_s` truncates the number, there are other ways like:

```
"%.2f" % a
```

or

```
(a * 100).to_i / 100.0
```